# UIImageView Scale to fill

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, scale

I have a `UIImageView` with a `UIImage` I set directly in the Storyboard/IB. I've also selected the `Scale to Fill` Mode

And this is what it looks like in IB/Storyboard:
[image]

However when I run the app it looks like this:
[image]

Any ideas on how I could fix this? I've tried changing mode in the storyboard/IB to say for example the center mode, this however just gives me a part of the image taken from the center of it.

Comment: You sure that u aint accidentally setting aspect fit in imageview maybe from code or storyboard

Comment: Yes I am unfortunately. I went thru the whole code and nothing is setting it to aspect fit, nore anything else like that.

Comment: can u set its scaling mode pogrammatically in viewwillappear or something like that and lemme know the result

Comment: Set the height of an image view solve your problem

Comment: So the problem seems to appear because I'm using constraints. If I remove the constraints it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I didn't connect constraints to all points. Doing so and making sure all constraint lines were blue solved it.